# infinite loop when double looping

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy, dataframe

I've got two csv files, df1 which has postcodes only and df which has postcodes and their corresponding longitude and latitude values.

```
import numpy as np
from math import radians, sqrt, sin, cos, atan2
import pandas as pd



df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users///UKPostcodes.csv")
df1 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users///postcode.csv")


X = df['outcode'].values
lat = df['latitude'].values
lon = df['longitude'].values

find = df1['Postcode District'].values

longitude = []

for i in range(0, len(find)):
    for j in range(0, len(X)):

        if find[i] == X[j]:
            print(find[i])
            #longitude.append(float(lon[j]));
```

I'm trying to loop through both files and find all of the longitude and latitude for df1, at the moment it runs an infinite loop, any idea how I can do this for all the values in my df1 file only and terminate once that limit has been reached?

edit: example of files:

[df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDkuU.jpg)

[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XOZX.jpg)

Comment: Can you post a small sample of your data and desired output?

Comment: Ideally, post the sample as code: `df = pd.DataFrame(<some inline literal>)` and the same for `df2`, s we can just run your code as-is, without needing any external files. [mcve] in the help should explain how to do this, if it's not clear.

Comment: Anyway, how do you know that it's an infinite loop, rather than just a very long but not infinite one? If, say, you have 20000 postcodes and a million outcodes, this will loop 20 billion times, doing two Pandas lookups and a comparison and possibly a `print` in each one, which could take a few minutes. (`print` is especially slow.)

Comment: Also, it would be much more efficient (and simpler, too) to either use a Pandas elementwise comparison rather than a loop, or to convert `X` into a `set` so you can just do `for f in find: if f in set_x: print(f)`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: For one thing, a MCVE would not include file input at all: just hard-code your data frames.  Most important, your posting must be self-contained, not depending on links.  Why does your code include transcendental functions and plotting routines?  How does the problem depend on those?

Comment: ive got around 14,000 rows in df and 3000 in df1, I'm basically trying to get the longitude and latitude for all the values in df however i have to compare df to df1 because the longitude and latitude reside there

Answer (score 0):

If your data in `df['outcode']` and `df1['Postcode District']` have the same formalism, I think you can use `merge` to create two columns (latitude and longitude) associated to the column `Postcode District` of `df1` such as:

```
df_output = df1.merge(df, how = 'left', left_on= 'Postcode District', right_on= 'outcode')
```

`df1` is the left DF and `df` is the right DF, `how = 'left'` means you keep all the keys from `df1`. `left_on= 'Postcode District'` and `right_on= 'outcode'` define the column on which merge happens for each DF. See [this link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for mote details on merge